# Is there a software center for Raspbian?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, free-software

Is there a software center for Raspbian? Ive tries downloading the Pi Store, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raspbian is Debian, so you have: `apt`, `apper`, etc.

`apt` is a command line tool. `apper` is a Graphical User Interface.

Software Centre, is a (Microsoft or Ubuntu) tool, based on Debian's system, but with proprietary intent (malware).